# Removing/undoing the only node in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

My code undos the added elements one by one starting with the latest add. It does everything correctly unless there is only one node left in a list and my code does not undo/remove it from the list. For example:

```
[A, B, C, D, E] //call undo()
[A, B, C, D] //call undo()
[A, B, C] //call undo()
[A, B] //call undo()
[A] //call undo() and it throws Exception here <------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I undo `[A]` it should return empty list `[]`.
NOTE: I HAVE TO USE A DUMMY NODE called `beginMarker` and `endMarker` which have a value of `null`, so the last element looks like this:

```
beginMarker <-> "A" <-> endMarker
```

For the last element, the code checks if the size equals to `1` and it's true and proceeds further but does not empty out the list. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 public void add(x){
         .........
         undoStack.push(newNode);
    }
    public void undo(){
            if(undoStack.isEmpty()){
                throw new RuntimeException("Undo history is empty");
            }
            else{
                Node<T> object = undoStack.topAndPop();

                redoStack.push(object);
                if(this.size() == 1){
                    beginMarker = object.next;
                    beginMarker.next = null;
                    //beginMarker.next = null;
                }

                if(object.prev == beginMarker){
                    beginMarker.next = object.next.prev;
                    object.next.prev = beginMarker;
                }

                else if(object.next == null){
                    object.prev.next = null;
                }
                else{
                    object.next.prev = object.prev;
                    object.prev.next = object.next;
                }





                theSize--;
                modCount--;
                countUndone++;
}
```

Class **SimpleStack**

```
public class SimpleStack<AnyType>{

  // Tracks the top node of stack.
  private Node<AnyType> topOfStack;

  // Construct the stack.
  public SimpleStack( ) {
    topOfStack = null;
  }

  // Test if the stack is logically empty.
  // @return true if empty, false otherwise.
  public boolean isEmpty( ) {
    return topOfStack == null;
  }

  // Make the stack logically empty.
  public void clear( ) {
    topOfStack = null;
  }

  // Insert a new item into the stack.
  // @param x the item to insert.
  public void push( AnyType x ) {
    topOfStack = new Node<AnyType>( x, topOfStack );
  }

  // Remove the most recently inserted item from the stack.
  // @throws UnderflowException if the stack is empty.
  public void pop( ) {
    if( isEmpty( ) )
      throw new RuntimeException( "SimpleStack pop" );
    topOfStack = topOfStack.next;
  }

  // Get the most recently inserted item in the stack.
  // Does not alter the stack.
  // @return the most recently inserted item in the stack.
  // @throws UnderflowException if the stack is empty.
  public AnyType getTop( ) {
    if( isEmpty( ) )
      throw new RuntimeException( "SimpleStack empty in getTop" );
    return topOfStack.data;
  }

  // Return and remove the most recently inserted item
  // from the stack.
  // @return the most recently inserted item in the stack.
  // @throws UnderflowException if the stack is empty.
  public AnyType topAndPop( ) {
    if( isEmpty( ) )
      throw new RuntimeException( "SimpleStack empty in topAndPop" );

    AnyType topItem = topOfStack.data;
    topOfStack = topOfStack.next;
    return topItem;
  }

  // A singly linked Node which contains data and a link to another
  public class Node<T>{
    public T data;
    public Node<T> next;

    public Node(T d, Node<T> n ){
      this.data = d;
      this.next = n;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What is `undoStack` ? What is the stacktrace ? BTW `NoSuchElementException` is a more adapted exception to throw here, or `IllegalStateException` (because of the name of your method, does not look like a collection)

Comment: Why don't you have a pointer at the end of the list ? It would make sense for a doubly linked list, this way you can iterate in reverse at no additional cost for example

Comment: @Dici, actually I have that, I've just updated the code again. I have a tail which is `beginMarker <-> "A" <-> endMarker` and still having troubles to return an empty list

Comment: If I understand well your markers, it should prevent any NPE to ever happen. If your `toString` method ignores both markers, then you're fine

Comment: It is axiomatic that a linked list algorithm will have problems near the ends, and when you have a doubly-linked list the number of bugs is squared.  You basically just have to be good at debugging, no matter how careful you believe you were designing and writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not be surprised the NPE occurs here :

```
if(object.prev == beginMarker){
    beginMarker.next = object.next.prev; 
    //                             ^^^^ 
    //                             is it here ? object.next is null in your case
    object.next.prev = beginMarker;
}
```

It should fix it to simply write

```
if(object.prev == beginMarker && object.next != null) {
    beginMarker.next = object.next.prev;
    object.next.prev = beginMarker;
}
```

However, you don't really have to particularize the case `size() == 1`. A simpler implementation would be (assuming you add a pointer to the end of the list) :

```
public void undo() {
    if (undoStack.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Undo history is empty");
    } else {
        Node<T> object = undoStack.topAndPop();
        redoStack.push(object);

        object.prev.next = object.next;
        object.next.prev = object.prev;

        theSize--;
        modCount--;
        countUndone++;
    }
}
```

This should work since using an `endMarker` will prevent you from having any `null` node in the list.

Comment: It's giving me this, @Dici, `[A, ]`. It seems to add a space maybe, after "A"

Comment: Uh, it's not supposed to add anything

Comment: Is your `endMarker` something like `new Node("")` ? This would explain this output if your `toString` method is incorrect

Comment: OMG! OMG! OMG! @Dici, you did it in 10 secs when I've been stuck on it since afternoon! Thanks! It works!

Comment: @John hahaha the more it hurts, the more you remember it next time

Comment: I'll surely remeber this method. @Dici, one last question, fo redo() would it smth like `object.prev.next = new Node(object.data, object.prev, object.next)` ?

Comment: You also have to set `object.next.prev` to this same new node. I would actually have a method that does this : `void link(Node node, Node prev, Node next)`. You will have to perform this kind of both ways linking a lot, so it would be useful. this method should set the following links: `node.next = next; next.prev = node; node.prev = prev; prev.next = node;`

Comment: When I do `object.prev.next = new Node(object.data, object.prev, object.next)` and `object.next.prev = new Node(object.data, object.prev, object.next)` it keeps popping the same element each time. Any ideas, @Dici?

Comment: Yeah cause you have to use the **same** node. It means, `Node newNode = new Node(...);` and then reuse `node`

Comment: Still getting the same thing, @Dici... I tried it: `Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(object.data, object.prev, object.next);
   object.prev.next = newNode;
   object.next.prev = newNode;`

Comment: Well actually you don't even need a new node, you can use `object`. If you don't manage to do it, I recommend you accepting this answer and posting a new one. Code in comments is not great :p